# Python Print element from lxml html

Tags: python, lxml.html

Trying to print out the entire element retrieved from lxml.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page=requests.get("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=INTC")
qtree = html.fromstring(page.content)

quote = qtree.xpath('//span[@class="time_rtq_ticker"]')

print 'Shares outstanding', Shares
print 'Quote', quote
```

The Output I get is

```
Quote [<Element span at 0x1044db788>]
```

But I'd like to print out the element for troubleshooting purposes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is function `tostring()` in `lxml.html`

```
import lxml, lxml.html

print( lxml.html.tostring(element) )
```

---

`xpath` returns list so you have to use `[0]` to get only first element

```
print( 'Quote', html.tostring(quote[0]) )
```

or `for` loop to work with every element separatelly

```
for x in quote:
    print( 'Quote', html.tostring(x) )
```

Comment: Thanks. Simplifies it and clears it up. Was trying to treat 'quote' as an element when it's a list.

Comment: is there a way to do this using the html5parser method without the weird html:div stuff?

from lxml import html
from lxml.html.html5parser import fragment_fromstring

html.tostring(fragment_fromstring('<div>hi</div>'))

# <html:div xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">hi</html:div>'

Comment: Is there an element method for printing it as a string? Something like `element.some_method()`?

Comment: @AndreasYankopolus element has no special method for printing - you have `lxml.html.tostring(element)` for this.